# Value object depends on other value object

Tags: design, domain-driven-design

As I understand, most of the business logic is stored in the value objects as constraints, like the `price` cannot be less than 0.

But I have a problem where the value object depends on another value object as a constraint.

Says we have 2 value objects `BasePrice` and `Price` in the `Product` entity. Both the `BasePrice` and `Price` could be set separately. But the `Price` cannot be, says, greater than `BasePrice + 1000`.

Since both of them can be set separately, if we update the `BasePrice`, the `Price` might be not valid anymore.

How to solve these dependencies between value objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all constraints can be validated within a value object.

If the constraint is about the relation between two VOs then the constraint has to be enforced by something that holds them both. In DDD this could be a third value object or an entity. In this case it sounds like that would be the `Product`.

That object can throw throw an exception if there's an attempt to create an invalid combination of `Price` and `BasePrice`. The [answer by Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/435476/23915) shows a nice way of doing that.

Comment: You may take the time to read my answer to see how the described constraint can be validated within the value object `Price`.

Comment: @DocBrown, yes that looks nice. It's still Product enforcing the invariant by throwing, but it's delegating most of the business logic to Price. You could also create a void function on price that asserts it's valid for the given base price and throws if not.

Comment: You are right. The solution of @DocBrown is the `Product` enforcing the invariant.

Comment: Both you and @DocBrown are great, but I could only mark one answer correct. Could you add a reference to DocBrown's answer? So I could mark your answer, since it's generally correct, and DocBrown's reference as a detailed implementation.

Answer (score 6):

A `Price` object which depends on an **updateable** `BasePrice` cannot be a value object, since value objects should be *immutable* (at least, by the book).

So if `Price` and `BasePrice` are both immutable, and `Price` holds a reference to a `BasePrice`, if one needs a price with a different base price, it will be necessary to create a new `Price` object with a new `BasePrice` passed in the constructor, so the old `Price` object stays valid. However, if `Price` and `BasePrice` should both be properties of a `Product`, this is probably not a good idea, since now the `Price` object of the product might reference a different base price than the `Product` itself.

Hence, when you want `Price` and `BasePrice` to be independent properties of your `Product`, each one should not know anything about the other directly. Therefore, the constraint "Price must be between BasePrice and BasePrice+1000" makes sense only in the context of a `Product` object. This constraint needs to be checked whenever a method like `Product.SetPrice` or `Product.SetBasePrice` is called.

Still, the business logic for checking against the base price can be part of the `Price` object. Design the latter with a method `IsInValidRange(BasePrice bp)`, and call it like this

```
   class Product
   {
        BasePrice basePrice;
        Price price;
        
        void ChangePrice(Price newPrice)
        {
             if(!newPrice.IsInValidRange(basePrice))
                  throw new InvalidPriceException();
             price = newPrice;
        }

        void ChangeBasePrice(BasePrice newBasePrice)
        {
             if(!price.IsInValidRange(newBasePrice))
                  throw new InvalidPriceException();
             basePrice = newBasePrice;
        }
   }
```

I guess your issue lies in the the phrase *"business logic stored in the value objects as constraints"* - better replace "stored" by "implemented", this yields to the kind of solution I sketched above.

Comment: Yeah, the old `Price` stays valid but logically, the `Price` should be updated according to the `BasePrice`, right? And when the data is read from the database, if we pass the updated `BasePrice` to the `Price` constructor, it is invalid. How do we let the user know about this?

Comment: For example, Amazon has a policy about the price the sellers can set according to the base price. If Amazon sets a new base price, do the sellers have to set a new price too?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn: how to handle constraint violations in your application is a completely different question than the one you asked, that's completely unrelated to value objects. But let me add some words on your scenario in my answer.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood somewhere. As I mentioned in my question, the value object, in my understanding, is responsible to protect the business logic, checking the data if it is valid, as the length of a string, the value of a number, etc. So the `Price` in this situation should make sure its value is in relative range to the `BasePrice`. If I misunderstand anything, could you kindly explain it to me, please?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn: see my edit. A value object can be made responsible for validating a constraint without holding a reference to other objects, just pass the required input through the validation method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a `thing` object that has two price values, not two separate objects. Since they have a dependency on each other it doesn't make sense to try and make the separate. From there your options are managing that relation in getter and setter methods of properties. In this case I would probably advise using explicit methods rather than something like a traditional .Net property, because there are side effects to changing these values that can be more clear with a method like `thing.updatePricing(5, thing.Price)` than `thing.BasePrice=5;`.

Comment: It's 2 separate objects. The `BasePrice` can't do anything with the discount and is only needed when setting the `Price`. The `Price`, on the other hand, can do something with the discount. So that makes them separate objects.